# Is it possible to access jquery functions through a templating library like Handlebars?

Tags: jquery, templates, handlebars.js

It might be easiest to explain the question with an example.

I have a handlebars template defined in an HTML page:

```
   <script id="myTemplate" type="text/html">
      <h1>{{fieldname}}</h1>
   </script>
```

I render the template with handlebars:

```
   var source = $("#myTemplate").html();
   var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
   var txt = template(jsonObj);
```

and txt ends up containing the rendered html text. No problem.

BUT...

say I've retrieved an XML file via ajax, and I'd like to use jquery to reach into it to render elements.

In order to retrieve, say, the value of the "name" child element from a parent element, I might use jquery like this:

```
   $(xml).find('name').text()
```

So, I thought my template might look something like this: (NOTE THIS DOES NOT WORK!)

```
   <script id="myTemplate" type="text/html">
      <h1>{{$(this).find('name').text()}}</h1>
   </script>
```

EDIT: Obviously, this doesn't work.

I also tried

```
{{this.find('name').text()}}
```

and even

```
{{.find('name').text()}}
```

But none of these work, and so far I've been unable to find any of the JS templating systems where you can do something like this. Handlebars and DUST seem the most likely to be able to do it, but I haven't had any luck thus far.

I've seen some indication that I could convert the XML to JSON and just pass that as the context, and that may indeed be the only way.

Is it easier than I'm making it out to be? Impossible?

EDIT:
After more digging, it looks like there's just not a templating solution for Javascript out there that works interchangeably with JSON or XML Dom objects for the data context. All of them appear to assume json.

Soooo... I used one of the many jquery plugins available to convert xml2json, and pass THAT object into HandleBars and everything works swimmingly.

The only trick that I ran into is if you perform a JQUERY query on the XML data to find a particular element, what you get back is an ARRAY of XML dom objects, even if there's only 1 result.

So, I had to do something like:

```
var txt = template($.xml2json($(xml).find('myelementname')[0]));
```

And all is good.

I may open another question about whether anyone knows of a Javascript template engine that takes either json OR xml dom objects.

Comment: I'm going to give the answer to Shankar because dot.js does actually come very close. I think I kind of prefer the logic-less template design of Handlebars and Moustache a little more, but dot.js could definitely be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that because the template parser do not know what `this` is. In the template you can only only play with the data you provide to it.

However you can take a look at [Underscore templates](http://scriptble.com/2011/01/underscore-js-templates/) of [doT js](http://olado.github.com/) they might be helpful to you.

Comment: Hmm, well, based on the docs for most of the template engines I've looked at so far, they all seem to indicate the use of a "context" which is to say, the data object that you pass to the engine to use for rendering purposes. By "this", what I mean is referencing that passed in object. Granted, my syntax above isn't correct. I'm just wondering if there is a way at all.

Comment: I got what you tried to say, check my edited answer it might help you.

Comment: Hadn't looked at those. I'll check em out. Thanks!

Comment: I have used both of those out of which doT js is very fast and you can have jQuery statements inside the template.

Answer (score 1):

From the [handlebar documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/) it looks like you could pass the xml into the template and use `Handlebars.registerHelper` to help extract the name element form the xml.

```
var context = { xmlData: xml, body: "I Love Handlebars!" };

<div class="post">
  <div class="body">{{body}}</div>
  <h2>The xml name:{{findName xmlData}}</h2>
</div>

//Register a helper
Handlebars.registerHelper('findName', function (someXML) {
  return someXML.find('name').text();
});
```

Comment: I read through the docs on the helper functions and it might work. My first thought was "Ugh, i'll need a seperate helper for each xml element I want to pull", but I suppose I could do something like
Handlebars.registerHelper('find', function (someXML, name) {
  return someXML.find(name).text();
});
and just pass the element name to find as a string parameter from the template:
<div class="post">
  <div class="body">{{body}}</div>
  <h2>The xml name:{{find xmlData, 'name'}}</h2>
</div>
but that seems a little hackish...

Comment: @drventure That doesn't seem like much of a hack if that's what the templating plugin is made to do. I don't see any adverse effect to using it that way.

Comment: Yeah, hack is probably too strong a word. Still, that just seems like it'd clutter up the templates more than I'd like. Using the xml2json routine and just giving handlebars what it wants in the first place seems much cleaner. Guess I was just thinking that surely there was a templating library that could directly render XML data.